# Why is my matlab code not generating the right answer?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

Execute 6 iterations of the QR method applied to the Hilbert matrix of order 18. Denoted by λ_i the approximations of the eigenvalues of A and by λ the eigenvalues that are computed by the command eig, the maximum absolute error max|λ_i- λ|is approximately:

A)7.4495e-03
B)7.4321e-01
C)7.8451e-05
D)7.1563e-08
E)7.9932e-10

For the above question
Matlab code, and Matlab function (`qr_base`) I used to solve the question on my own, for some reason I do not understand I have a completely different answer.

Could you please take a look and assist me to see what my problem is?
The codes I used are described as follows:

```matlab
close all;clear;clc;
m_max = 6;
A = hilb(18);
[d,m] = qr_base(A,m_max)
val = eig(A)
err = max(abs(d-val))

function [d,m] = qr_base(A,m_max)
%convergence is guaranteed only if A has eigenvalues with distinct absolute value
for m = 1:m_max
   [Q,R] = qr(A);
   A = R*Q;
end
d = diag(A);
end
```

I was expecting to get the answer (which is the correct one) after approximating the eigenvalues using the QR method with the function, and subtracting from it the default eigen values generated by MATLAB function `eig`. But I get a different value which is not the answer.

Comment: Aren't MATLAB function contents supposed to be indented?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki No, MATLAB doesn’t require indentation, and standard convention has always been to not indent the function body.

Comment: I have looked at the code, the backslash is the only weird thing I saw. I think the code should work as required. What you can do is ensure you’re running the code you’re showing us, and not some other function elsewhere, by running line by line in the debugger and noting which files the debugger shows you. Sometimes a different file with the same name comes first on the search path, and we don’t realize we’re running different code…

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have removed the backslash since it was a typo. And yes I run the code too but I got around 1.8 something, the answer is not even in the options(I am trying to not jump to the conclusions that the answer provided by the prof is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

`eig` returns the eigenvalues sorted from smallest to largest. Your function  `qr_base` returns them sorted from largest to smallest.

So if you flip the result of the function you'll get a correct error measure:

```matlab
function [d,m] = qr_base(A,m_max)
for m = 1:m_max
   [Q,R] = qr(A);
   A = R*Q;
end
d = diag(A);
d = flip(d);  % Added line
end
```

The output I get now is `err = 7.1563e-08`.

---

Note that I realized what the problem was the second I took a look at both `d` and `val` in the script. These are the numbers you're comparing, take a look at what you're comparing if the comparison doesn't yield the expected result. MATLAB is easy to get started in because it is so easy to examine the value of variables and see what is being computed, and how. You can very easily run a script line by line by just copy-pasting each line in the command window, you don't even need to learn to use the debugger (though that would be highly recommended!).